# MathJax not converting TeX in dynamic element React/Redux

Tags: html, reactjs, math, redux, mathjax

As a disclaimer, I'm new to MathJAX and TeX syntax.

I'm having trouble trying to transform the following:

```
<div class='challenge__description'>
  The Ackermann function is usually defined as follows
  $$A(m, n) =
   \begin{cases}
   n+1 &amp; \mbox{if } m = 0 \\
   A(m-1, 1) &amp; \mbox{if } m &gt; 0 \mbox{ and } n = 0 \\
   A(m-1, A(m, n-1)) &amp; \mbox{if } m &gt; 0 \mbox{ and } n &gt; 0.
   \end{cases}$$
  Its arguments are never negative and it always terminates...
</div>
```

And I have the following before my `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} });
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.querySelector('.challenge__description')]);
</script>
```

But nothing seems to happen. Everything prints out as is without any transformations. It works fine [by itself](https://jsfiddle.net/12v5zrkg/).

An important note is that I am trying to apply MathJax transforms in React/Redux. I am dynamically setting the contents of `challenge__description` div using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

`react-mathjax` does not seem to solve this problem as it wraps the TeX representation in a React component for processing. If I'm setting everything directly with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, then the `<MathJax.Node>` componentization of the TeX code is meaningless as the tags take on no special meaning.

Comment: Did you add this `<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}
});
</script>`?

Comment: @typeofnull I just did after the cdn file. Didn't do anything for me.

Comment: post a fiddle @mythereal

Comment: @typeofnull Okay that's really strange, because it works in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12v5zrkg/), but it doesn't work in my app..

Comment: I'm using React and setting the innerHTML using approximately the above. Maybe there's an unwanted behavior/interaction with MathJax when that happens.

Comment: Try adding `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.getElementById('your element id')]);`, if your loading it dynamically.

Comment: @typeofnull Doesn't work, I get the same results. :(

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: You might want to post your code so that other people can help as well.

Comment: The docs show the config before the call to load the mathjax script

Comment: You should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mathjax

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for the help! Yeah I was looking into that. It most certainly is a problem with dynamically processing the content. I'm just a bit hesitant to port in such a low-volume package. Might be the only easy solution though.

Comment: On second thought, I don't even know if react-mathjax would help as I'm dynamically setting the innerHTML. If I do that, the component tags `<MathJax.Node>` etc. won't take on special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being quite simple. In the component that needs updating with MathJax, simply include the MathJax `Config` and `Queue` in the lifecycle methods:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  MathJax.Hub.Config({ tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]} });
}

componentDidMount () {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.querySelector('.challenge__description')]);
</script>
}

componentDidUpdate () {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.querySelector('.challenge__description')]);
</script>
}
```

Comment: It works now, I created a new component and passed the js loaded from latex to it using dangerouslysetInnerHTML Thanks!